# Matching valid phone numbers in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get the valid phone numbers from a string. Can you please help me out :

```js
var s = 'This is a mobile number example : 09540298880,+91-9540298880,+919540298880,919540298880,8888888,-91888880';    
var r = /([0-9]+){1}|(\+[0-9]+-{4})+[0-9]+/g;    
console.log(s.match(r));
```

It should give this Valid (output) Phone Numbers:

```
09540298880,+91-9540298880,+919540298880
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion:

```
\b\d{11}\b|\+\d{2}-?\d{10}
```

From your input, it matches:

```
09540298880
+91-9540298880
+919540298880
```

```js
var s = 'This is a mobile number example : 09540298880,+91-9540298880,+919540298880,919540298880,8888888,-91888880';    
var r = /\b\d{11}\b|\+\d{2}-?\d{10}/g;    
console.log(s.match(r));
```

## [Test it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7MOaQZ/2)

Answer (score 1):

Try with below regex your number format is Indian standard, I've created my regex based on that,

```js
var string = "09540298880,+91-9540298880,+919540298880,919540298880,8888888,-91888880"

var result = string.match(/(?:[0\+])(?:[7-9][1]{1,2}\-?)?(?:[0-9]{10})/g)

console.log(result)
```

```
(?:[0\+])(?:[7-9][1]{1,2}\-?)?(?:[0-9]{10})
```

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/77RELi/4)

Comment: [Your regex matches `+91--------------------------`](https://regex101.com/r/77RELi/3). I don't know indian standards, but it may be an invalid result.

Comment: Thanks very much @Mistalis